# Show that $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \ge abc(a+b+c)$ For real $a,b,c$.

Tags: inequality

Show that $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \ge abc(a+b+c)$$
For real $a,b,c$.

---

I tried to use:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{i}^{2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3}b_{i}^{2}\right)\ge\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{i}b_{i}^{}\right)^{2}$$
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge(ab+bc+ca)^2$$

But expanding and simplifying did not give the answer,I also used this approach:
$$\left(ab+bc+ca\right)^{2}=a^{2}b^{2}+b^{2}c^{2}+c^{2}a^{2}+2abc\left(a+b+c\right)$$

So we need to show that:
$$\left(ab+bc+ca\right)^{2}-2abc\left(a+b+c\right)\ge abc\left(a+b+c\right)$$

Or equivalently:
$$\left(ab+bc+ca\right)^{2}-3abc\left(a+b+c\right)\ge 0$$

But I don't know how to that.

Comment: I would point out that the notion $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}{a}$ is better than $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3{a_i^2}$ because the latter does not clear what sequence $a_i$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put $x=ab,y=bc,z=ac$ we have to prove $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx$$ $$\iff \frac{1}{2}({(x-y)}^2+{(y-z)}^2+{(z-x)}^2)\ge 0$$

Comment: @masaheb because $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=1/2(\sum {(x-y)}^2$

Comment: @masaheb yes! right

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2(b-c)^2+ b^2(c-a)^2+ c^2(a-b)^2 \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Divide by $2$ and rearrange.